# Best way to save a file which is manipulated by df

Tags: pandas

I have a excel file which contains test result of around 20000 tests. I want to write a dash application on it to get real time status. And also when the tests are run the file will get updated. How to manage such a scenario with one base file. Currently I am using excel file which gets replaced every time a test is run trying to update the status. Will SQLITE3 be a better way. I want a base file which has to updated by tests(only one row at a time) and read by a dash application all the time without any errors. What is the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to append results to an existing file, pass `mode='a'` to the I/O method. Check 4th example for `to_excel` method in the pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html).